# How to set the ng-template value from the component

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-template, angular9

I have this in my HTML file:

```
<div>
  <ng-template  #valueTemplate>

  </ng-template>
</div>
```

How can I set the innerHtml of the `ng-template` using my local reference `#valueTemplate` from the component?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css'],
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('valueTemplate', { static: false }) valueTemplate;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postContentEditContent.innerHTML(data.content); // Doesn't work
    this.postContentEditContent.value(data.content); // Doesn't work
    this.postContentEditContent.setValue(data.content); // Doesn't work
    this.postContentEditContent.textContent(data.content); // Doesn't work
  } 
}
```

How can I set its value from the component?

Answer (score 2):

`<ng-template>` won't be created in the DOM as it is just a template.

You should bind to an element that will get created in the DOM, such as a `<div>`.

As a bonus, you can bind using the `innerHTML` property.

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

To do this you will need to mark it as safe HTML in the component:

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

content: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<p>Hello, world!</p>');
}
```